# How do I create a list like the one in the Android Youtube app?

Tags: android, android-layout

If you go to your watch history or favorites in the Youtube app, that is the list I'm talking about. The videos are listed with the thumbnails as the background, the video info on top of it, and an arrow in the corner for a context menu.

I would like some information on how to make something just like that. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own Adapter for the List, here is a guide to help you get started:

http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/

The principle is the same, you just need to adapt it to your situation. Use your own layout and add your own view objects.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Try googlin custom adapter.

Comment: I did not know it was called a Custom Adapter. Thank you